# Does "build with local dependencies" exist in Maven without multi-module?

Tags: maven

I have a set of applications, all use Maven and the local repository. The applications form a dependency tree using `<dependency>` in their `pom.xml`. All of these projects have `-SNAPSHOT` in their version.

**Is it possible for Maven (or some compatible dependency manager) to build an application together with all of its local dependencies whose source changed?**

I do not want to create a multi-module project, because:

- the projects are exactly libraries, not modules;
- I do not want an additional complexity just to have a form of build which is already precisely defined;
- I want the process to be dynamic: if a library is mature enough to be put into a remote repository, it would be no more rebuilt with the main project and that's ok.

For now, there is a lot of refactoring, moving code from one library to another etc. and it happens often that substantial parts of the dependency tree need to be rebuilt. I thus need to manually write `mvn install` in several projects in order to assure that there is no stale code.

Comment: do you mean that you want to keep your custom libraries separately and application code in another place? And not having this coupled in one project, cause you don't wanna carry library code along with application code. Is that right?

Comment: is this question about whether local libraries are accessible to other code on the same machine, using maven?

Comment: Yes. These libraries are sometimes reused by several projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. Even with a multi-module project, maven does not detect which modules have changed sources in it and which do not.

There was a (flaky) implementation in Maven 2, but it was not continued in 3.x, see [How to get maven 3.0 to only build modules with local scm changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852398/how-to-get-maven-3-0-to-only-build-modules-with-local-scm-changes)

I hoped they would include it again in maven 4, but I didn't see it yet: https://maarten.mulders.it/2020/11/whats-new-in-maven-4/

I once did a similar setup, but had to use shell scripts with some git magic to get it working.

You can also decide to put your libraries in separate repo's from the start, and use the `repo` tool that google uses for android development: https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/git-repo/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Once you run `mvn install` on the particular Maven project, it will be accessible for all other Maven projects, which are on the same workstation, during dependency collection (before the *compile* phase).

[Official Maven Build Lifecycle description](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html):

> `install` - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally

It's not necessary to keep libraries as part of the same project(or have it as a multi-module project). But once you want to share those libraries with your teammates, you would need either to force them installing libraries locally (as you did), or store those libraries at some external repo, like *Artifactory* or *Nexus*

Comment: I know, the problem is, I often need to run `mvn install` manually in multiple projects. I would want that command to be run by some automated dependency tracker in any project which needs to be rebuilt.