# Maven and Gradle: recompile if file modified

Tags: maven, gradle, ant, incremental-build

**EDIT:** The feature I asked about is a part of what is called incremental build.

I [was told recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66068184/8564676) that Maven does not have any arbitrary time stamp-based mechanism of verifying if a dependent file needs recompiling. Modification time is a base concept of `make` or Ant. I used it extensively in build scripts of Ant for a fine-grained recompilation of various files in formats unknown to IDEs.

Do Maven has chosen to operate only on JAR versions instead? If yes, how it works together with the fact that its configuration file is often also the main build file of a project? How to represent in a `pom.xml` file the modification-time dependent dependency logic which is commonly used in `Makefile` or `build.xml`? If via a plugin etc., then should a plugin be used for each, sometimes obscure, compilation type? Are there such plugins which take into account the modification time?

Possibly, I should not expect from Maven a functionality which is provided by something else? Are there some third-party tools which add the functionality in question to Maven projects? Are they compatible with IDEs, i.e. an IDE's `clean&rebuild` would rebuild outdated parts of the local project tree, as in the case of Ant projects?

And finally, is Gradle similar in the aforementioned aspect to Maven?

Comment: Usually, in Maven you just rebuild everything. For testing, you may rely on the incremental builds of your IDE (like e.g. Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, Gradle has that feature. It is called
[incremental build](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-incremental-build-support) and allows at once Ant-like flexibility and Maven compatibility.